# Remove shortlink link and meta tag generator

Tags: 7

I try to remove shortlink and generator link from [my site](http://landberg.at/nl/projecten/bramberg-mountain-resort).

```
<meta name="generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)">
<link rel="shortlink" href="http://landberg.at/nl/node/109">
```

I used below code in `template.php` but when i look in my source code its still there?

```
function landberg_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
    unset($head_elements['system_meta_generator']);
    foreach ($head_elements as $key => $element) {
        if (isset($element['#attributes']['rel']) && $element['#attributes']['rel'] == 'canonical') {
          unset($head_elements[$key]);
        }
        if (isset($element['#attributes']['rel']) && $element['#attributes']['rel'] == 'shortlink') {
          unset($head_elements[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

What is best way to remove this?

Comment: Your code is correct. Make sure that you cleared the cache.

Comment: @Aram Boyajyan i already cleared cash but the code is still showing up?

Comment: Strange; I checked the code and it works fine. Is the name of your theme exactly `landberg`? Add there a watchdog entry (e.g. `watchdog('debug', 'hook_html_head_alter() called from the theme');`) to make sure it is executed.

Comment: it was because it was overwritten by Meta tag module... Thanks

Comment: Good catch - glad you managed to resolve it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above code is good but it didn't work because it was overwritten by [Meta tag module.](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) I adjust some settings in `Configuration » Search and metadata` and now `generator tag` and `shortlink` is gone.

Comment: That is a proper solution. Sadly it needs to be done on all Metatag elements.

Comment: You could also simply add `unset($head_elements['metatag_shortlink']);` to your above snippet. Although I don't like how this then invalidates the admin UI. As no matter what anyone will put in these fields on the Metatag settings form, the values will be overwritten by that line.